# Lightning - Thousand Comma Separators for Picklist labels

Tags: salesforce, lightning

I want to add thousand separators to the labels of the following picklist.
No change should be made to the values, instead displaying text should use thousand separators.

```
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.myValues}" var="item">
            <option text="{!item.label+ ' km'}" value="{!item.value}"/>
     </aura:iteration>
```

In the list "myValues", I have values such as "300000". These are texts not integers.

Can someone help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [lightning:formattedNumber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedNumber/example) component.

Example:

```
<lightning:select label="Number?">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.myValues}" var="item">
        <option value="{!item.value}">
            <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!item.label}"/> km
        </option>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```